# How do I get Twitter OAuth to work with the Sorcery gem in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth

I am currently having trouble getting OAuth to work in Rails 4 using the Sorcery gem.  I have followed this tutorial on the Sorcery wiki to set everything up https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/External and right now I am getting to this page during the authentication process with Twitter: 
[image]

BUT when I click on the "Sign in" button, the callback URL isn't triggered properly.  I have supplied the exact callback url that was given by Sorcery in this line of code in the `sorcery.rb` file:

```
config.twitter.callback_url = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/oauth/callback?provider=twitter"
```

I've tried various things to get this to work, I've tinkered around with the "Permissions" in the Twitter developer console and I've try different configuration options but nothing has worked.

This is the code responsible for doing the callback from the Oauths controller generated through sorcery:

```
def callback
        provider = auth_params[:provider]

        if @user = login_from(provider)
          redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Logged in from #{provider.titleize}!"
        else
          begin
            @user = create_from(provider)
            @user.activate!
            reset_session # protect from session fixation attack
            auto_login(@user)
            redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), :notice => "Logged in from #{provider.titleize}!"
          rescue
            redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Failed to login from #{provider.titleize}!"
          end
        end
    end
```

If anyone could provide any advice, suggestions or feedback, or if anyone has had experience doing this then that'd be greatly appreciated.

Please ask if you need more information to understand what I'm trying to do here.

Also does anyone think that Twitter might have changed something in their API that may make it incompatible with the current version of the Sorcery gem?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens at callback? What do you mean by `callback URL isn't triggered properly`? Does it stay at the Twitter authentication page?

Comment: The callback just stays at the Twitter authentication page and doesn't redirect to my app.  Do you have any idea why this might be happening?  I copy and pasted the exact callback URL from the sorcery.rb file into the application details in the Twitter API console

Comment: It might help to see what you are doing in the action that maps to the   `POST "oauth/callback"` route.

Comment: @SteveRowley Hey I've added the code responsible for the callback, take a look at it above in my revised post

Comment: Sorry @Jamaal nothing jumps out at me. Assuming your routes are set up in the same way as the example on the wiki page, the only thing I could think of might be that `http://0.0.0.0:3000` is not the URL of your app, but I get the feeling it is from the screenshot you provided.

Comment: @SteveRowley http://0.0.0.0:3000 is the URL in my app and right now I'm just trying to test everything ind development, and it's not working.  I keep on thinking of other ways to get this to work, thanks for your help I really appreciate it!